# Maintaining a total balance of debit/credit sales transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, finance

The overall intent is to consolidate individual sales transactions to total debits/credits summing up the totals by year and month--retaining a running balance from start to end. This code uses multiple `#temp` tables. I am interested in having this code reviewed in order to find a more efficient way to achieve this.

The `create table` and `insert` statements are for the convenience of the code reviewer, should s/he choose to execute the code.

```
CREATE TABLE SumTest(
    POSDate datetime NULL,
    debit money NULL,
    credit money NULL,
    RollingBalance money NULL,
    expires datetime NULL,
    ExpiringDebitBalance_2013 money,
    ExpiringDebitBalance_2014 money
);

-- mimic actual sales transactions

insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Jan  5 2013 12:00AM','670.00','22.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Jan  6 2013 12:00AM','821.00','0.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Mar  8 2013 12:00AM','62.00','700.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Mar 11 2013 12:00AM','78.00','29.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Mar 11 2013 12:00AM','900.00','87.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Apr 16 2013 12:00AM','0.00','440.00',NULL);
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Aug 18 2013 12:00AM','0.00','50.00',NULL);
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Aug 19 2013 12:00AM','470.00','200.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Dec 31 2012 12:00AM','1000.00','200.00','Dec 31 2013 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Dec 22 2013 12:00AM','200.00','0.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Dec 20 2013 12:00AM','500.00','0.00','Dec 31 2014 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Nov 10 2012 12:00AM','200.00','0.00','Dec 31 2013 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Nov 11 2012 12:00AM','150.00','0.00','Dec 31 2013 12:00AM');
insert into sumtest (POSDate,debit,credit,expires) values ('Nov 15 2012 12:00AM','0.00','100.00',NULL);



create table #work
(   
    POSYear int NULL,
    POSMonth int NULL,
    debit money NULL,
    credit money NULL,
    RollingBalance money NULL,
    expires datetime
)

-- start with ditching the time

insert into #work
    (POSYear,POSMonth,debit,credit,expires)
select datepart(Year, POSDate) as POSYear
      ,datepart(Month, POSDate) as POSMonth
      ,debit
      ,credit
      ,expires
from sumtest



-- dump an ordered set by year,month with a rolling balance of all points/redemptions

;with distilled as
  (select POSYear,
          POSMonth,
          TotalDebit = sum(debit),
          TotalCredit = sum(credit),
          expires
   from #work
   group by POSYear,POSMonth,expires
   )

select POSYear,
       POSMonth,
       TotalDebit,
       TotalCredit,
       RollingBalance =  sum(totaldebit + (totalcredit)*-1) over ( order by POSYear, POSMonth),
       expires
into #work2
from distilled
order by POSYear,POSMonth,TotalDebit,TotalCredit



-- filter out credits lines that dont have an expiration date 

select x.POSYear,
       x.POSMonth,
       sum(x.TotalDebit) as TotalDebit,
       sum(x.TotalCredit) as TotalCredit,
       x.RollingBalance,
       EXPYear = datepart(Year, y.expires),
       EXPMonth = datepart(Month, y.expires)
into #work3
from #work2 x
    inner join #work2 y on x.posyear = y.posyear
                 and x.posmonth = y.posmonth
where y.expires is not null
group by x.posyear,x.posmonth,x.rollingbalance,y.expires
order by posyear,posmonth

-- add back in lines that are single credits, w/o debits

INSERT INTO #work3
    (POSYear,POSMonth,TotalDebit,TotalCredit,RollingBalance,EXPYear,EXPMonth)
select 
    POSYear,
    POSMonth,
    TotalDebit,
    TotalCredit,
    RollingBalance,
case 
    when expires is null then (POSYear + 1)
end as EXPYear,
case 
    when expires is null then 12
end as EXPMonth
from #work2
where (POSYear + POSMonth) NOT IN (
           select POSYear + POSMonth
            from #work3)
```

Comment: i can't even get this to build on SQLFiddle.com.  there are a bunch of places where the column names don't match, etc  please look over your post and make sure that it is correct

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b4a0/1) I changed some things, if you could get this to work please post the new fiddle.

Comment: If running totals is the central theme of this snippet, you might want to take a look at this [detailed analysis of various calculation methods](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals "Best approaches for running totals").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always make sure **nothing breaks if you accidentally execute your script twice**.

Your script should begin with verifying whether table `SumTest` exists (and `DROP` it if it does), *before* creating it.

Temporary tables `#work`, `#work2` and `#work3` are never dropped. Not a biggie, but if you run the script twice you'll get an error saying `there is already an object named '#work' in the database`. **Dropping your `#temp` tables is a good habit to take.**

As for the naming, well, @Malachi's answer says one thing, I'll say another: **be consistent. it's all that matters.** - if you drag-and-drop columns and tables from the SSMS object explorer into your query, then by all means stick to `UPPERCASE`. Personally I find uppercase SQL is annoying to read, it's like all those keywords are jumping at you. Do what you will. I mean, chose whether you prefer `UPPERCASE` or `lowercase`, and **stick to your plan**.

Answer (score 2):

it is good Coding Practice to Capitalize all of the Reserved SQL words so that it is easier to tell them apart.

words like `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `WITH`, `INTO`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `CREATE TABLE`, `INSERT INTO`, `END`, `CASE`, `AS`, `IS NULL`, `THEN`

I know this is Kind of Nitpicking, but you should get into the habit of doing it, even though SQL is not Case Sensitive on these.

I know this isn't the review that you were looking for, but it seems you have an issue that you need to fix before we can review this code

Comment: Oh boy!:-\ That's the best we can do? I thought "working code" was the operative phrase. What I have works--what I don't have is code that is good. I'm willing to admit that so I can move forward with a better approach.

Comment: I will take a closer look at it later, if I get the chance before I leave for the day, as long as the code functions.

Comment: @Malachi actually if this is written is SSMS or VisualStudio, or even NotePad++, keywords are highlighted in bright blue so IMHO they're already easy to tell apart. I like lowercase SQL, I find it's much easier on the eyes. As always what really matters is consistency: there's no reason  for `CREATE TABLE` and `NULL` (vs `create table` and `null`) if you're going to `insert into` some `values` (or `select from`)... especially if you're later going to `create table`. That said I find the CR syntax highlighting could be improved.

Comment: I posted this on meta: [Could syntax highlighting be improved?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/935/could-syntax-highlighting-be-improved)

Comment: I didn't necessarily mean in CR alone, I meant in the IDE, but that is a good point as well.

Comment: @Malachi so, where's the rest?

Comment: @Malachi nevermind, got it :)